# SQL VARIABLE RENAME IN QUERY

Tags: sql, variables, rename

I have a table called ORDPAY, a field in the table is called Paid_Flag. I want my query to show me something in replace of the actual paid_Flag value.  For exmaple if paid_Flag = 1 I want the Query output to display 'Cash', if paid_Flag = '2' i want the Query OUtput to display 'Check'.  How can i code this into my select statement results

Comment: Hint:  `CASE` expression.

Comment: but can you do a CASE expression in a CAST(select) for xml output

Comment: You don't need cast here

Comment: @MaryMahoney . . . Your question specifies nothing about XML output.

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon said, the CASE expression is what you need. It would look something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN paid_Flag = 1 THEN 'Cash'
            WHEN paid_Flag = 2 THEN 'Check'
            ELSE 'unknown'
       END AS newPaidFlag
FROM <yourTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Select Case Paid_Flag
            When 1 then 'Cash'
            When 2 then 'Check'
            Else 'Error'
       End output
From ORDPAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `CAST` , all what you need is `CASE`:

```
DECLARE @ORDPAY TABLE ( ID INT , Paid_Flag INT);

INSERT INTO @ORDPAY VALUES
(1,1) , (2,2);

SELECT ID,
Paid_Flag = CASE Paid_Flag
            When 1 then 'Cash'
            When 2 then 'Check'
END
FROM @ORDPAY
```